# Changing a Column Choice value and updating the column value for any previously saved items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, column, calculated-column, choice-field

I have a list with a choice column which has muliple choices, so that the user can pick from a selection.

Would like it so that the choice list is updatable (i.e can change the names) at a later date and then any existing item's value for that column are also updated. However currently when the column choice is updated, the value for any previously saved items in the list don't already change.

For e.g.
1) Have a list with a choice column called Country which has two options, UK and France.
2) Add a new item to the list with value of UK.
3) Edit the list choice values meta data so that UK option now is renamed to England.
4) Item added in 2) is still UK.

Is there any way to get the change in 3) to be reflected in all items?

Answer (score 1):

It introduces other complications, but your best bet may be a lookup field.

Create a secondary custom list called Countries. Then build a lookup column in the first list which references the Countries list values.

Now your example will work the way you intend.

Comment: If you use lookup columns be aware of limits and thresholds (maximum number as of 2013: 12). If only Microsoft would have been able to provide us with a proper key-value choice field.